# Applying DC bias on a high voltage rectified ripple 570VAC peak down near to zero

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, mains, three-phase

I am working on a linear power supply with a 3-phase input. I wondering if there was a possibility to shift the  rectified (ripple) power signal shown below which spans between 560VAC to 505VAC (55VAC difference @130 ohm load) down near to the zero so imagine it could span between 0 to 55VAC.

[image]

If the voltage above is adjusted, then I imagine the voltage supply will need to go into a power transformer with a ratio of 3:1 then a go through a diode in series (half-wave rectification) then if needed go through a linear regulator for ripple reduction and voltage regulation within reasonable expectations.

- My target is to set up a 12V ~100mA linear power supply from 3-phase (4-wire) 330V (max)/phase 50Hz.
- I've tried to use this high pass filter to adjust the bias but:

  1. It shifts mostly under zero, several iterations got me no-where.
  2. Under very small loads @100K ohm load, I'm getting results above zero  around 20VAC, can't get it near that when load increases.

  [image]

Note: I am bound to have galvanic isolation (transformer) in my application.

I would really appreciate if someone would kindly share their thoughts.

Comment: That doesn't look like an AC power signal to me. It looks like the ripple left after three phase rectification.

Comment: yes, that is correct. Can this signal  be still manipulated as i imagine ? ; offset adjusted --> transfer through a transformer with the designated turns ratio --> cleaned with caps ?

Comment: I expect it can but please make it clear in your question that you wish to use ripple voltage that is AC coupled to a transformer or other suitable converter. Details that relate to the question are best kept in the question.

Comment: @Andyaka edited the title and description. Would you have any thoughts on this matter ?

Comment: I probably wouldn't use a transformer, rather I'd remove the DC content with a capacitor and current limiting resistor and protect that output with a TVS diode and then use a rectifier and buck regulator to get the 12 volts

Comment: @Andyaka thanks for sharing your thoughts. As i understand it is not feasible.

Comment: Can you explain why it isn't feasible? I'm asking so that people don't suggest it as an answer.

Comment: Your 'high pass filter' removes the DC component, so you need a rectifier to get DC voltage out of it. Why is this 'not feasible'?

Comment: I need to use a transformer as isolation is needed in my application, i understood from the suggestion above that it is not possible to handle the ripple voltage (bring it down from 500V+ area down to 55V-ish region by adjusting the Bias) before introducing the voltage supply into the transformer then clean it .